# Is the issue with this question about the experimental procedure, or about what's being asked of the final state?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Is the problem with [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144336/does-carbonation-permanently-increase-the-acidity-of-soda-water)

1. that it's not clear which experimental procedure I'm proposing, or
2. that it's not clear what I'm asking about the final state of the water samples, or
3. that I didn't provide enough detail about the experimental procedure to determine which sample of water will end up more acidic?

If (3), what additional information needs to be provided?

Comment: Hmm, to be honest, I don't really think your question is unclear. I will wait a while for one or more of the close voters to chime in, though, before deciding whether to mod-reopen.

Comment: Actually, I must have clicked through and didn't bother inspecting it before VTC. I am in agreement with @orthocresol that it should not be closed. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @orthocresol Thank you for offering to reopen the question. It doesn't seem like anyone objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments, I don't see  anything particularly wrong or unclear about your question. I have reopened the question.